# 2x2 images with text overlay different on each

Tags: html, css, background-image, centering

Okay, preface: I am an extremely amateur coder. As in, I just started last week and what I am basically doing is looking up "how to do x" and then combining it with "how to do y" and "how to do z" in an awkward little combination of ideas and code.

What I am trying to do is place 4 images in a 2x2 orientation with decent enough spacing to get a good view of some of the background and have it all centered on the page and semi responsive (I'm not really worried about mobile or going to extreme, but I'd like it to appear decent on different browser sizes/changing screen size etc.

Again, I'm very rookie at this and am having trouble reconciling all the details. I know the code is sloppy and probably "wrong", but I'm just doing it to play around. SOOOO I'm just trying to center these images on any page with decent spacing.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url("http://static1.businessinsider.com/image/587621bcdd08953f208b491a/14-eerily-beautiful-photos-of-europes-first-underwater-art-museum.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 48%;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 15%
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s ease;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 15%
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: .75;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/96/3b/ee/963beeb07d222d64094a25bc3840b532--easter-bunny-a-bunny.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        It's a vampire bunneh!!! BUNNICULA!!!! YES!!! HAHAHAHA
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Q6xybdaV3xs/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <ul>
          <li>This really isn't my text</li>
          <li>But I'm playing with it anyway</li>
          <li>To show my UL stuff</li>
          <li>or something of that nature</li>
          <li>Hi and thank you</li>
          <li>if you choose to help</li>
          <li>Or if you just want to laugh and watch</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.herts.ac.uk/__data/assets/image/0009/66717/rocket_car_launch.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        I thought this thing was kinda cool
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Spaceball_jump_over_Skydive_35.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        I've always wanted to go skydiving!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, yeah. The clunky stuff I have that is probably horribly set-up and confusing, but I just went in trying to follow what made sense to me at that point logically rather than with any overall background knowledge. Any help would be appreciated, even if it's to tell me "you're an idiot, start over completely or stop coding because you suck". =P

Comment: You want to show this as a 2x2 grid with same spacing to all four corners?

Comment: Yes. I want to place them "centered", I suppose with the same spacing on all sides within the page so that the background is still visible and they're not askew or anything.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you mean? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvaOxY

Be careful with `position`, you seem to be using it a bit too much when it's not needed. Place your elements with `padding` and `margin` instead of absolute position and `top, bottom, left, right`, as this can cause you problems with responsive elemets and break things if you are not careful.

Using Bootstrap you could achieve this with a few classes and no custom css.

Playing along is how we all start learning, keep it up and try new things.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: That's closer than I was. It gives me something to play with and think about. Thank you for your time and effort. :)